# Disabling Jface menumanager (grey out)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have a menumanager "menuManager" that holds menu items (actions)  and a sub-menu, another menumanager "subMenu" that contains more actions.

```
final MenuManager subMenu = new MenuManager("Main",null);
subMenu.add(mActionClose);    

MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu", "contextMenu");
menuManager.add(action1);
menuManager.add(action2);
menuManager.add(subMenu);
```

I can only set setEnabled(false) on actions and not on menumanager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding `isEnabled()` method of [`MenuManager`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/MenuManager.html) doesn't have any effect. What you can do is get access to related [`MenuItem`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/MenuItem.html) and try to disable it.

First, you add [`IMenuListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/IMenuListener.html) to your "context menu" manager to access associated [`Menu`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Menu.html):

```
public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
    manager.getMenu().addListener(SWT.Show, showContextMenuListener);
}
```

In the listener you find the `MenuItem` that matches your sub-menu manager:

```
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    for (MenuItem item: ((Menu)event.widget).getItems())
        //MenuItem data should be our MenuManager
        if (item.getData().equals(subMenu)) {
            //Disable the sub-menu item
            item.setEnabled(false);
            //Add listener to sub-menu (see comments below the code block)
            item.getMenu().addListener(SWT.Show, showSubMenuListener);
        }
}
```

The problem with this is that there's a bug fix code in `MenuManager` class that will re-enable your sub-menu item once it is clicked (in case it contains any items). To override this you also need to add `SWT.Show` listener to the sub-menu that will update the enablement of sub-menu item when the menu becomes visible after a click:

```
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    ((Menu)event.widget).getParentItem().setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: @vanaprogeja, the first part of the answer is good (up vote), but I don't want to override menumanager's methods, just too much mess.

Comment: Do I have to use listeners to make it disabled?

Comment: @kenny you might not have a reference to the item before it becomes visible, so a listener is probably the only way to go. I modified my answer to avoid overriding MenuManager.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set enabled==false on the jface `MenuManager`, and when I looked through the code I didn't see it using `isEnabled()` during its rendering.  I know in most cases it simply doesn't render a submenu if that menu is empty.

In popup menus, it will disable a submenu if on an `SWT.Show` event it can determine that there are no children, but I think that behaviour is a little counter-intuitive.

A decent UX behaviour is to always have that submenu there, but have it expand to one disabled menu item when it should be used: "<no actions available>" or "<not enabled>" or something like that.

Comment: I don't think that disabling just the items is user friendly... I can do a trick: remove the sub menu, replace it with some dummy regular item (with same caption) and disable it, but i don't like it much.